# Problem with utf8 and \maketitle

Tags: titles, input-encodings, listingsutf8

I have the following master document:

```
\documentclass[tesi,english]{editorialupv}
\input{preambulo}
\bibliography{referencias}
\graphicspath{
    {../figuras/}
    {../logos/}
    {./figuras/}
    {./logos/}
    }

\author{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\centering Methodology
        \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{.75em}}l}
            Autor:      & Jean-Michel Clairand\\[4ex]
            Director:   & D. Carlos Álvarez Bel\\[.5ex]
                                \end{tabular}
        }
    }

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\abstractname}

\input{cap_Resumen}

\ifEPUB
\else
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}

    \tableofcontents
\fi

\mainmatter


\listoffigures

\listoftables

\input{1Introduccion}
\input{2V2G}

\bibitemsep = 3ex
\bibhang = 2em

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=\bibname]

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

And my preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{eurosans}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\ifEPUB
backend=biber 
    \makeatletter
    \def\blx@shorthands{} 
    \makeatother 
    \ifcastellano\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla,es-sloppy]{babel}\fi
    \ifvalencia\usepackage[catalan]{babel}\fi
    \ifenglish\usepackage[english]{babel}\fi
    \newcommand{\sen}{\on{sen}}
    \date{}
\else
    \ifcastellano\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}\fi
    \ifvalencia\usepackage[catalan]{babel}\fi
    \ifenglish\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage{csquotes}\fi
    \newcommand{\sen}{\on{sen}} 
\fi

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,longtable,multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb}




\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[
    url = false,
    style = authoryear,
    hyperref = true,
    backref = true,
    backend = bibtex, % Otra opci�n es 'backend = bibtex'
    %backend = bibtex,
%   style=numeric,
        ]{biblatex}


\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\ifEBOOKPDF
    \colorlet{colorEnlace}{red!75!black} 
\else 
    \colorlet{colorEnlace}{black} 
\fi

\usepackage[
    {colorlinks},
    {linkcolor=blue!75!black},
    {citecolor=green!75!black},
    {urlcolor=colorEnlace},
    {bookmarksnumbered},
    {breaklinks},
    ]{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thenomenclature{%
    \section*{\nomname}%
    \if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi
    \nompreamble
    \list{}{%
        \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
        \leftmargin\labelwidth
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
        \itemsep\nomitemsep
        \let\makelabel\nomlabel}}
\makeatother


\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ifenglish
    \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={.}}
\else
    \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\fi

\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = {\;}] \EURO{\geneuro}

\ifEPUB
    \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\Picture[#2]{./figuras/#2.png width="500px"}}
\fi


\ifEPUB
    \newcommand{\incluyeGrafico}[2][]{\Picture[#2]{./figuras/#2.png width="500px"}} % Por compatibilidad
\else       
    \newcommand{\incluyeGrafico}[2][]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}} % Por compatibilidad
\fi

\newcommand{\ingles}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\textit{#1}\/}
\newcommand{\miUrl}[1]{{\small%
    %\texttt%
    {\underline{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\matlabr}{{\sc Matlab}$^\circledR$\xspace}
\newcommand{\simulinkr}{\textit{Simulink}$^\circledR$\xspace}
\newcommand{\matlab}{{\textsc{Matlab}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\simulink}{\textit{Simulink}\xspace}

\newcommand{\scr}{\textit{script\/}\xspace}
\newcommand{\scrs}{\textit{scripts\/}\xspace}


\definecolor{griset}{rgb}{.925, .925, .925}

\ifEPUB

    \newenvironment{parrafoDestacado}
        {
        \HCode{<div class="parrafoDestacado">}
        }
        {
        \HCode{</div>}  
        }

\else

    \newsavebox{\mybox}
    \newenvironment{parrafoDestacado}
        {%
        \fboxsep = 2ex
        \fboxrule = .4pt
        \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
        \begin{minipage}{.85\textwidth-2\fboxsep}\itshape\parskip=2ex
        }
        {%
        \end{minipage}
        \end{lrbox}%
        \begin{flushright}
            \colorbox{griset}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
            %\fcolorbox{black}{griset}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
        \end{flushright}
        }

\fi

\ifEPUB

    \newenvironment{Resumen}
        {
        \HCode{<div class="Resumen">}
        }
        {
        \HCode{</div>}  
        }

\else

    \newsavebox{\myboxb}
    \newenvironment{Resumen}
        {%
        \vspace*{-2.0cm}
        \fboxsep = 0pt
        \fboxrule = 0pt
        \begin{lrbox}{\myboxb}%
        \begin{minipage}{.85\textwidth}\itshape\parskip=2ex\parindent=2em
        }
        {%
        \end{minipage}
        \end{lrbox}%
        \begin{flushright}
            \usebox{\myboxb}%
        \end{flushright}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        }

\fi


\newcommand{\on}{\operatorname}



\ifcastellano
    \newtheorem{teorema}{\upshape\bfseries Teorema}[section]
    \newtheorem{lema}{\mdseries\scshape Lema}[section]
    \newtheorem{proposicion}{\upshape\bfseries Proposici�n}[section]
    \newtheorem{ejemplo}{\bfseries\scshape Ejemplo}[section]
\fi

\ifvalencia % Es mantenen els mateixos noms per compatibilitat, per� l'autor els pot personalitzar
    \newtheorem{teorema}{\upshape\bfseries Teorema}[section]
    \newtheorem{lema}{\mdseries\scshape Lema}[section]
    \newtheorem{proposicion}{\upshape\bfseries Proposici�}[section]
    \newtheorem{ejemplo}{\bfseries\scshape Exemple}[section]
\fi

\ifenglish
    \newtheorem{teorema}{\upshape\bfseries Theorem}[section]
    \newtheorem{lema}{\mdseries\scshape Lemma}[section]
    \newtheorem{proposicion}{\upshape\bfseries Proposition}[section]
    \newtheorem{ejemplo}{\bfseries\scshape Example}[section]
\fi


\newcommand
    {\parBlanca}
    {\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
```

When I compile, I have the errors:

No \title given. \cleardoublepage

Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined(inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'. \cleardoublepage

The initial template wasn't using utf8, but I changed it in the command \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} because I need it. The problem is in the \maketitle command because when I erase it it compiles it, but without the cover page.
How can I use the \maketitle command without these errors?

Comment: In your preamble you have a `backend=biber ` without loading `biblatex`

Comment: You have  no `\title{...}` in your preamble, that's what the .log says first. Try adding a title and see what happens.

Comment: Load `hyperref` last except for known exceptions, such as `cleveref`. Note that nobody can reproduce your issue as you've not posted a proper MNWE.

Comment: Is there any news here? Right now, the question cannot be answered. Or rather, an answer can only rely on guessing.